# Nach einem wundervollen Konzert mit großartigen Publikum geht es am Rhein entlang nach Basel

Tags: sentence-structure

Entlang describes that its along the river. But why was "an" used here? "entlang" is more related to movement along something ... while "an .... entlang" is more related to existence without movement. So I wonder why did he put "an" while the sentence is talking about active movement towards the city of Base.

Comment: I am more concerned about _mit großartige**n**_, because it should be _mit großartige**m**_.

Comment: this is right ... it should be großartigem

Answer (score 4):

Your observation is wrong, there is no such connection with movement or simple presence. *An+Dativ+entlang* is common for both:

> Sie ging am Ufer entlang, als …
>
> Ein Weg führte an der Mauer entlang.

*Entlang+Genitiv* is a bit old-fashioned or even poetic:

> Sie ging entlang des Ufers, als …
>
> Entlang der Mauer führte ein Weg.

A third option is

> Sie ging das Ufer entlang.
>
> Ein Weg führte die Mauer entlang.

This uses *entlang* as a bare adverb. It changes the meaning of the verb directly. Some even think *entlanggehen* and *entlangführen* are separable verbs taking the thing passed as an accusative object.

---

I think your confusion comes from the fact **an** ist one of the **dual-way prepositions**. That's true. But *entlang* required the genitive in the past, and using *an+Dativ* is a more recent development. So, this particular *an-entlang* isn't dual-way but a strictly dative preposition.

Similarly, *an-heran*, *auf-drauf*, and *in-hinein* are strictly accusative prepositions, though bare *an*, *auf*, and *in* are dual-way.

Comment: should not the sentence be:  " ... geht es den Rhein entlang nach Basel"?

Comment: This is also possible, I'll edit my answer to address it.